# Sitecore 6.4.1 Captcha fails to validate valid input on first attempt

Tags: internet-explorer-8, sitecore, captcha, sitecore6

It seems that when attempting to submit a form in Sitecore with captcha validator it fails in IE 8 on first attempt and succeeds on the second.

Is this a bug in IE or sitecore. I am assuming it has to be one or the other. Not sure where to start on this one. It supposed to work out the box so not even sure I want to be looking under the hood in the first instance.

Any suggestions on how to approach this one?

Cheers

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: nope, if I remember correctly we had to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view seems to be a Sitecore bug, I have the same problem in a Sitecore 7.2 (rev. 140526) instance and always after the page load (either first time accessing the page or refreshing without postback data) the validation for wffm captcha field fails.

Works fine after a submit so probably a bug in code, anyone has any idea of a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit like a page lifecycle issue. Assuming the validation is server-side, check if it occuring too late?